# When proving $\liminf(a_n)>L$, proving $\liminf(a_n)>a$ with $a<L$ is enough?

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, convergence-divergence, limsup-and-liminf

> Let $\epsilon>0$, can I prove $\liminf(a_n)>L$ by proving $\liminf(a_n)>1-\epsilon$?

I'm proving that $$\liminf \sqrt[n]{a_n}\geq \liminf \frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}$$

To do so I took $\liminf \frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}=L$ and than with $a=L-\epsilon \quad$ I proved that $\liminf \sqrt[n]{a_n}\geq a$. Is it enough to say that $\liminf \sqrt[n]{a_n}\geq \liminf \frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}$?

Comment: Do you realize that you are asking if $M>a$ for every $a<L$ implies $M>L$? What do you think the answer is?

Comment: $L>M>a$. In this case $M>a$, $L>a$ but $M \ngeq L $. That's why I wasn't so sure.

Comment: ?? Are you answering my comment? I cannot be sure, sorry.

Comment: @Did yep, I forgot to tag.

Comment: How is the string of characters in your comment addressing mine? This is what I fail to understand.

Comment: @Did I asked if $M>a$ for every $a<L$ implies $M>L$. I didn't know if the case $L>M>a$ was possible, because, if it was, then it wouldn't be true. That's why I wasn't sure about the answer.

Comment: Since you now asked an answer, would you say that $M>a$ for every $a<L$ does imply $M>L$, or not?

Comment: Yes, I would. (for $\geq$)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You proved that, for every $\epsilon>0$
$$\liminf\sqrt[n]{a_n}\geq L-\epsilon$$
We can then take the supremum on the right-hand side:
$$\liminf\sqrt[n]{a_n}\geq\sup_{\epsilon>0}L-\epsilon=L$$